# Using Invoke-Command within a function

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, invoke-command

I have this code snippet. The idea is calling an invoke command on a remote pc, but if the command fails, then it should retry.

The code looks like this:

```
Function Run-Command 
{
    param(

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)] 
        [Uri[]] $ConnectionUri,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)] 
        [PSCredential] $Credential,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)] 
        [ScriptBlock] $ScriptBlock,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)] 
        [Int] $Time,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)] 
        [Object[]] $ArgumentList

    )

    for($retry = 0; $retry -le 10; $retry++)
    {
      try
      {
        Invoke-Command -ConnectionUri $ConnectionUri -Credential $Credential -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock -ArgumentList $ArgumentList #-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue           
        if ($?)
        {
          break
        }

        Write-Verbose "Server is not ready yet . . . sleeping and trying again in $Time seconds."
        Start-Sleep -Seconds $Time
      }
      catch
      {
        Write-Verbose "Server is not ready yet . . . sleeping and trying again in $Time seconds."
        Start-Sleep -Seconds $Time
      }
    }

}
```

I should then be able to call the function as this:

```
Run-Command -ConnectionUri $ConnectionUri -Credential $Credential -ScriptBlock $SomeScriptBlock -Time 30
```

But for some reason it does not work as I thought it would.

Thanks in advance

Regards
Magnus

Comment: I forgot to say that if I run the Invoke-Command outside of the function with whatever I call the Run-Command function with, it works. So the problem lies within the function and not the invoke-command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. For anyone interested, here is the code:

```
Function Run-Command 
{
    param(

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)] 
        [Uri[]] $ConnectionUri,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)] 
        [PSCredential] $Credential,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)] 
        [ScriptBlock] $ScriptBlock,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)] 
        [Int] $Time,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)] 
        $ArgumentList

    )

    for($retry = 0; $retry -le 10; $retry++)
    {
      try
      {

        if ($ArgumentList -eq $null)
        {
            Invoke-Command -ConnectionUri $ConnectionUri -Credential $Credential -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        }
        else
        {
            Invoke-Command -ConnectionUri $ConnectionUri -Credential $Credential -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock -ArgumentList $ArgumentList -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        }

        if ($?)
        {
          break
        }

        Write-Verbose "Server is not ready yet . . . sleeping and trying again in $Time seconds."
        Start-Sleep -Seconds $Time
      }
      catch
      {
        Write-Verbose "Server is not ready yet . . . sleeping and trying again in $Time seconds."
        Start-Sleep -Seconds $Time
      }
    }
}
```

I suspsect the reason for it not working was that the argumentlist was sometimes empty. So I added a check to decide which Invoke-command to run.

Hope this migth help someone

/Magnus